# System.NullPointerException when using .contains in a for loop

Tags: apex, string, null-pointer

I am iterating through an array of a List of Maps and want to run an if function whenever an item from the list meets a condition.

The problem I am currently facing is Salesforce producing the following error:

> System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Here's the code with some more explanations:

```
    for ( Integer i=1; i<allRows.size(); i++ ){
          //this system.debug is to iterate over all lists, extract the values
          //under the 'Names' header and display them in debug (IT WORKS)
          system.debug(allRows[i].get('Names'));
          String namesRow = allRows[i].get('Names');
          //The below debug also produces the correct values          
          system.debug('namesRow is ' +namesRow);
          //When the below function is active I am getting the NullPointerException Error
          if (namesRow.contains('Andrew')){
            system.debug('this name is in the database!');

          }

        }
      }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check if a variable is null before you de-reference it:

```
if (myVariable != null && myVariable.contains('<substring>'))
{
    // do stuff
}
```

When you call `myVariable.someMethod(...)`, the system tries to de-reference the value of `myVariable`. If it is null, you will get this exception. Any time you have a value which could possibly be null, you should protect yourself with null checks like the above.

Note that if statements perform short-circuit evaluation, and that is why your variable would never get de-referenced using the above pattern. It would be essentially the same as:

```
if (myVariable != null)
{
    if (myVariable.contains('<substring>')
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error when using your if class, for your reference, that's how it looks: `if (namesRow != null && namesRow.contains('Andrew')){
        system.debug('this name is in the list!');

      }`

Comment: @KamilMieczakowski Did you replace `if (namesRow.contains('Andrew'))` entirely?

Comment: yes, I also pasted it in the above comment for your evaluation

Comment: @KamilMieczakowski Then you are getting the error on a different line. Double check your stack trace.

Comment: Could it be the fact that I am getting the relevant string from a list of maps? that's what it is: String investmentsRow = allRows[i].get('Names'); It works when I debug it...

Comment: I don't know why you would put a `null` map in a list...you haven't shown us how you build that list so it's impossible to answer.

Comment: Sorry Adrian, it worked now. It must have been the API not being responsive for a split second. Thank you for your help! As an FYI I didn't put a null map in a list, it's just some values in some maps in the list are null while others aren't.

Comment: That makes more sense. Avoid null collections wherever possible.